# How to populate faclete page acording to css ID?

Tags: java, jsf, for-loop

I have a faclet, that looks like this:

```
<table id="blocks" >
    <tr>
        <td id="A2"></td>
        <td id="B2"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td id="A1"></td>
        <td id="B1"></td>                
    </tr>
</table>
```

I want to populate it with a List. I have a list of Users `List<Users>` with two properties: `userName` and `userPrivileges`.

```
for (Users temp : Users) {
    if (condition1) {
     // put it under id "A1"
    } else if (condition2) {
     // put it under it "B2"
    }
}
```

How to add this in .xhtml page to make it work?

Comment: This String comparison `user.name=="John"` is incorrect. I presume you already know about it. You are nowhere using JSF and/or Facelets in the present code snippets.

Comment: Thanks for replay. I didt realy look what I have wrote, sorry about that, I am stucked with some code, and I have no idea about JSF i just want to get that list be shown somehow..

Comment: This is your friend: https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/jsf-facelets.htm#GIEPX